# Use of "is" and "are" before the word "family"

Tags: grammar

I want to ask if this sentence correct?

> The greatest happiness in life are family happiness?

Is the "is" or "are" before the word family correct ?

Comment: 'Family' is used as a modifier here. Like an adjective (What he wants is a _small_ dog / Those are _large_ dogs) it has no influence on the correct choice of verbform. Here, the subject is 'The greatest happiness in life' and the subject always determines the correct verbform. Whether one considers 'happiness' here a non-count or a countified singular usage, the singular verbform 'is' is required.

Comment: Edwin said it well but to maybe explain more simply, it must be "is" because "are" is the wrong verb form for the subject. Are is used for plural things. This is a singular subject "the greatest happiness". If you changed it to a plural you could use "are".

Answer (score 1):

The correct phrasing is, 'The greatest happiness in life is family happiness?' because 'family' is functioning as an adjective in this sense, and 'happiness' is an uncountable noun that is grammatically treated as singular.

When 'family' is a noun, you can treat it as singular or plural depending on context. If you are talking about the family as a whole unit, treat it as singular, e.g. my family is strange, if you are talking about your family members, treat it as plural, e.g. my family are all doctors.